# Changing label content using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to change label content using javascript?

```
<label>How is it?</label>
<input type="button" value="change label"/>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Do you have any specific question about it?

Answer (score 1):

Give the label an ID and change it like this:

```
<label id='label-id'>How is it?</label>
<input type="button" value="change label"
       onclick="document.getElementById('label-id').innerHTML = 'Like this!';"/>
```

(Forgive the inline event handler. :-) )

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/bd349/

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have posted, this code would work:

```
var label = document.getElementsByTagName('label')[0], // first label
input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]; // first input

// attach click handler
input.onclick = function() {
    label.innerHTML = 'changed label';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use jQuery?

```
$('label').text("whatever you want here");
```

With JS:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].innerHtml = "whatever you want here";
```

It would be best to give it an ID so you can target it directly.