# how to put value on a label in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I put the value of a variable on a label using JavaScript?

```
function myFunction(id) {
var x=document.getElementById(id);   

document.getElementById('l_id').value = document.write(x.id);
}

<label id="l_id" ></label>
<a href="docview.php?id=25" id="1" onclick="myFunction("1")" target="iframe_a">July 3,    2013</a>
```

I want to put the value of the variable `x` on my label. How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: i want to put the vlaue i get on a label.. sample i get var x="hello" how can i code it to put it on label?

Comment: Try changing this document.getElementById('l_id').value = document.write(x.id); to this document.getElementById('l_id').value = x.id;

Comment: Only form control elements have a `value` property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing label content using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531494/changing-label-content-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `innerHTML` of the `label` to equal `x`, Like so:

```
x = //value;
document.getElementById('yourelement').innerHTML=x;
```

Comment: I think you mean innerHTML :-)

Comment: I try it but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

`document.getElementById('l_id').innerHTML = x.innerHTML;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = "sometext";
var myElement = document.getElementById('1_id');
myElement.innerText = x; //chrome and IE
myElement.textContent = x; //For firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

How come you wrote element.value = document.write();
Fatal mistake that document.write cannot be called after loaded.

```
function myFunction(x) { 
 document.getElementById('l_id').innerHTML = x;
}
<label id="l_id" ></label>
<a href="docview.php?id=25" id="1" onclick="myFunction('variable x')" target="iframe_a">July 3,    2013</a>
```